# How to make ASP.NET MVC work in IIS 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have installed .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and ASP.NET MVC CTP in a Windows Server 2003 R2 box, but my ASP.NET MVC site still doesn't work on that server. I was searching the internet and IIS for a solution and I noted that I can't choose other .NET Framework version besides 2.0 for my virtual directories. I'm almost sure if I correct this I can make my site work there.

Currently the main "/" URL answers with:

```
Directory Listing Denied
This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.
```

And the "/Default.aspx" URL answers with:

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Section or group name 'system.web.extensions' is already defined.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Phil Haack has a pretty good writeup here

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar issue.

1. I recently upgraded my server to support .net framework 4.0.
2. Converted my application to support .net fx 4.0.
3. Deployed the application on sever and trying to test .. I get "HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found"

**Solution**

1. Open IIS Manager, expand the master server node (i.e, the Servername node), and then select the Web service extensions node.
2. In the right pane of IIS Manager, right-click the extension "ASP.NET v4.0.*".
3. Click the Allow button.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Jason's answer, the common things to look for is:

- Enable Wildcard mapping and point it to the aspnet assembly Phil mentions in Jason's link.

The /default.aspx error you are getting seems to be a web.config configuration error.  At the very top of your web.config, look for:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions"
```

Most likely it is defined twice.  You only need the reference for the RC build you have.  If you need the exact RC references, create a new ASP.NET MVC Web Project in a temp folder.  And then grab the web.config from it.

-E

Comment: I have not found where it is defined elsewhere, but I had to remove from my Web.Config this section, and then it worked. But Jason's tip also helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem, in my case the solution was to uninstall the ASP.NET MVC Beta.

The application I was trying to get working had the version 1 MVC dlls bin deployed and once the Beta was uninstalled it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue: We tried to install an MVC4/.NET 4 app on an IIS6 box, set up everything as described, and got same error:

```
Directory Listing Denied
This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.
```

For us, the final fix was to add the UrlRoutingModule to the web.config:

```
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
       type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Which makes sense, but I don't know why we needed to explicitly add it and others didn't.  (We are running in a directory under Sharepoint, maybe related...)